# Register own Service Worker on Angular alongside its own worker

Tags: angular, service-worker

I have an web application that needs to work offline. I want to create my service worker to handle the API caching/sync logic, and let the angular's service worker cache the application assets.

I got the Angular worker to register and work perfectly. But I could not get to register my worker.

I tried three methods:

```
//1. Does not seem to do anything. No worker built, no worker starter.
ServiceWorkerModule.register('./offline.worker', {enabled: environment.production});

//2. The worker does not get built, registering fails since the script does not exist.
navigator.serviceWorker.register('./offline.worker');

//3. The worker gets built, it even gets started, but is not registered as ServiceWorker.
new Worker('./offline.worker', {type: 'module'});
```

So, option 1 works fine using the docs on the angular service worker when we point to the ngsw js file. Maybe it is simply not made to work for our workers?

Option 2 is the documented/standard way to register service workers, maybe I should simply get my worker to be built? I do not know where to start to do that... The complete error I get is

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8080/') with script ('http://localhost:8080/offline.worker'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.

Option 3 gets everything done as I would have expected. My worker is compiled the `./offline.worker` is even changed to the bundle created! That's really how I would have expected to get things going. Unfortunately the worker created like so is only a web worker, not a ServiceWorker. This means it does not get to handle FetchEvents...

For sake of completeness, here is my tsconfig.worker.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/worker",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "webworker"
    ],
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.worker.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

And the commands used to launch angular in production mode since service workers do not worker in develop:

```
ng build --prod
http-server dist/app
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We've added custom logic along-side the Angular Service Worker by using a simple intermediary script to load both the generated ngsw script and our own custom script. This plays well with the Angular build process.

#### app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  //...
  imports: [
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('sw-master.js', {
      enabled: environment.production
    }),
    //...
  ],
  //...
});
```

#### angular.json

```
...
"assets": [
  ...
  "src/manifest.json",
  "src/sw-custom.js",
  "src/sw-master.js"
],...
```

#### sw-master.js

```js
importScripts('./ngsw-worker.js'); // generated by Angular build process
importScripts('./sw-custom.js');
```

#### sw-custom.js

Just an example... we were making it so users could click on push notifications and be directed to a particular app view.

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';
  self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
    event.notification.close();
    if (clients.openWindow && event.notification.data.url) {
      event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url));
    }
  });
}());
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. That is very close to what we are doing now. The problem we are having is that we'd very much want to have all the goodies from the Angular builder, for some shared classes, logics, etc. Kind of like what the new Worker method does, I'd like exactly that, but for a serviceworker. I can deal with importing the ngsw file.

Comment: Are you trying to use Angular classes and libraries within your custom service worker? What goodies from the builder are you referring to?

Comment: No we're not using angular classes, I doubt it would work. Mostly Typescript interfaces, and model classes.

Comment: I am sorry Adam, I meant to give you the bounty if no better answer would come but my son is born and got me out of SO for some time, just enough for the bounty to expire...

Comment: What a crazy coincidence. My first was just born too -- on the 30th haha

Comment: @AdamDunkerley why are you first importing ngsw-worker.js and then sw-custom.js? Since angular's service worker responds to fetch events it means that you can't access them in you custom code. If you reverse the imports you can still do some custom logging and/or override certain responses.

Comment: @enjoyYourProgramming Seems like something worth considering if you need to do those things. Thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: not working in angular 6

Comment: So is there a way to code your stuff into your `sw.custom` in typescript or just plain javascript...? looking for a solution including a separate thread serviceWorker with plain ng code.... at least typescript code

Answer (score 0):

**Only one service worker per scope is allowed to be registered**, so you can not register more than one service worker.

You can handle both API caching/sync and application assets caching in a single service worker file.